# Difference between Codahale metrics and Dropwizard metrics

Tags: java, cassandra, dropwizard, metrics

I'm new to Java. While exploring the ways of monitoring Cassandra, I found out(https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html) that "Metrics in Cassandra are managed using the Dropwizard Metrics library". However, at several places I've read about Codahale Metrics which has got me confused regarding the difference/relationship between the two.
Are these different libraries doing the same thing or is it that what's called as dropwizard metrics used to be called as Codahale Metrics earlier?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `Metrics` library have changed its package naming with versions as its changed hands in ownership a bit

```
yammer->codahale->dropwizard
```

They are all same library but dropwizard is the more up to date version

Comment: dropwizard still uses com.codahale as package name.